# Error on PostgreSQL: Line number: 1 - value too long for type character varying(10)

Tags: django, postgresql, amazon-rds, django-import-export

I'm able to do a bulk upload via django's ImportExportModelAdmin without a problem on my localhost and on the staging application. But when I try it on prod, it displays an error. One thing to note the key difference is that I am using SQLite for my local and staging sites. But prod uses Amazon RDS PostgreSQL database.

I haven't encountered this problem since, and I don't know where to start looking.

Here is the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/ubuntu/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
psycopg2.errors.StringDataRightTruncation: value too long for type character varying(10)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/ubuntu/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/import_export/resources.py", line 668, in import_row
self.save_instance(instance, using_transactions, dry_run)
File "/home/ubuntu/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/import_export/resources.py", line 446, in save_instance
instance.save()
File "/home/ubuntu/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 727, in save
force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
File "/home/ubuntu/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 765, in save_base
force_update, using, update_fields,
File "/home/ubuntu/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 868, in _save_table
results = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, returning_fields, raw)
File "/home/ubuntu/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 908, in _do_insert
using=using, raw=raw,
File "/home/ubuntu/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/ubuntu/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1270, in _insert
return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(returning_fields)
File "/home/ubuntu/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1416, in execute_sql
cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "/home/ubuntu/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 66, in execute
return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
File "/home/ubuntu/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 75, in _execute_with_wrappers
return executor(sql, params, many, context)
File "/home/ubuntu/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "/home/ubuntu/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
File "/home/ubuntu/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.DataError: value too long for type character varying(10)
```

Comment: Difference is SQLite does not really enforce types(see here [Quirks](https://sqlite.org/quirks.html) 3) Flexible Typing) and Postgres does. So you obviously have a least one value that exceeds 10 characters in length. Moral of story, do your development on the database you will be using in production.

Comment: Change from CharField to TextField. As Adrian said, use the database you would use in prod for development.

Comment: You can run postgres in dev using docker-compose - the example app [can do this](https://github.com/django-import-export/django-import-export/blob/main/tests/bulk/README.md#create-postgres-db).